# Will does this circuit require any resistors for its 7-segment display?

Tags: led, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

The circuit I'm trying to build is attached as a logisim simulation screenshot. The source is a 5V battery. The display is a [5161AS](http://www.dipmicro.com/?datasheet=TOS-5161AS.pdf) common-cathode display.

I've seen people use resistors whenever they use LED displays.

Now, my question is: will resistors still be necessary in this circuit? Isn't the current already going through the internal resistance of the components?

[image]

Comment: How many ohms are the internal resistance of the components?

Answer (score 2):

The resistors limit the current through the LEDs in the display to a safe level for the LEDs.  Many modern logic ICs can put out more current than is safe for a LED without the resistor, so you need the resistor to stop this from happening.

Comment: ... thus you need a resistor.